# Posting html values in Jquery to Controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have the following script which contains html data appended to it  :

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#drug_id').change(function (){
         option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
         html='';
         htmlhead='';
        // alert(option)
         $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:"<?php echo base_url();?>transactions/details_now/"+option,
             dataType:"json",
             success:function(data){
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                   // alert(data[i].commodity_name)
         html += '<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>transactions/issues" method="post"><tr>\n\
        <td><input type="text" id="commodity_name' + i + '" name="commodity_name' + i +'" value="'+data[i].commodity_name+'"/></td>\n\
        <td><input type="text" id="transaction_type' + i + '" name="transaction_type' + i +'" value="'+data[i].transaction_type+'"/></td>\n\
        <td><input type="text" id="Available_Quantity' + i + '" name="Available_Quantity' + i +'" value="'+data[i].Available_Quantity+'"/></td>\n\
        <td><input type="text" id="Quantity_Ordered' + i + '" name="Quantity_Ordered' + i +'" value="'+data[i].Quantity_Ordered+'"/></td>\n\
        <td><input type="text" id="batch_number' + i + '" name="batch_number' + i +'" value="'+data[i].batch_number+'"/></td>\n\
        <td><input type="text" id="date' + i + '" name="date' + i +'" value="'+data[i].date+'"/></td>\n\
        <td><input type="text" id="username' + i + '" name="username' + i +'" value="'+data[i].username+'"/></td>\n\
        </tr> <input type="submit" value="Issue"></form>';
        }
        htmlhead+='\n\
             <th>Commodity Name</th>\n\
             <th>Transaction Type</th> \n\
            <th>Batch Number</th>         \n\
            <th>Available  Quantity</th> \n\
            <th>Ordered Quantity</th>  \n\
            <th>Department</th>\n\
            <th>Requestor Name</th>\n\
            ';
       $('#thead').append(htmlhead);
        $('#you').append(html);

             },
             error:function(data){

             }
         })

     });
     });</script>
```

I want to post the values in the input fields to  the controller when I click the issue button.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
//delegated submit handlers for the forms inside the table
$('#you').on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //read the form data ans submit it to someurl
    $.post('someurl', $(this).serialize(), function () {
        //success do something
    }).fail(function () {
        //error do something
    })
})
```

Comment: I have tried it this way : //delegated submit handlers for the forms inside the table
$('#you').on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //read the form data ans submit it to someurl
    $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>transactions/issues', $(this).serialize(), function () {
        //success do something
        alert("Success");
    }).fail(function () {
        //error do something
        alert("Failed");
    })
}) But still I get undefined index in my controller page. This is how I called it this way in my controller : $transaction_type=$_POST['transaction_type'];

Comment: @user689017 what happened then?

Comment: @user689017 in your html the name of the element has a sequence number also remove it.... like `<td><input type="text" id="transaction_type' + i + '" name="transaction_type" value="'+data[i].transaction_type+'"/></td>`... in the controller it is expecting a parameter with name `transaction_type`, but you have like `transaction_type1`, `transaction_type2` etc